# Where are these obects stored in memory?

Tags: java, class, memory, types

I am using data types to declare some value and on other hand i am using concept of wrapper class to store value, so where these objects or literal values are stored in memory?

```java
class raw {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 5;
    Integer aa = new Integer(5);
    // where these values are getting stored
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int a = 5` is stored in stack,

and `new Integer(5)` object is stored in heap. The reference variable `Integer aa` is stored in stack memory.

For every thread, it has a isolated stack memory, and all of those threads share the heap memory.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the wrapper class as just any other object in Java. The literal value that it stores is stored as a primitive variable in the object.

In case of an Integer, it's stored in an int variable which is defined in Integer class as `private final int value;`

Look at the source code of class here http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/lang/Integer-source.html.